# Laplace and differential equations equal to a bounded continuous function

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I am stuck with this task: "Let *r(t)* be a bounded continuous function that is zero outside of [-M, M], M>0. Express the solution of the following problem as an integral:

$$y'' + 2y' - 8y = r(t)$$

where y(0) = - y'(0) = a

r(t) is confusing me. So far I got this when I Laplace both sides:

$$s^2Y-sy(0)-y'(0)+2(sY-y(0))-8Y = R(S)$$
$$Y=\frac{1}{s^2+2s-8}\cdot R(s)+\frac{sy(0)+y'(0)+2y(0)}{s^2+2s-8}$$

And let's say that:
$$ \mathscr{L}(k(t)) = \frac{1}{s^2+2s-8} $$

So that,
$$y(t) = \frac{sy(0)+y'(0)+2y(0)}{s^2+2s-8} + (k\circledast r)(t)$$

--
What do I do now to get the solution as an integral? I know the convolution can be expressed as an integral, but I just do not know how to continue with my k and r.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As

$$
k(t) = \mathcal{L}^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{s^2+2s-8}\right)=\frac{1}{3} e^{-t} \sinh (3 t)
$$

we have

$$
k(t)\circledast r(t) =  \frac{1}{3}\int_0^t e^{-t+\tau} \sinh (3 (t-\tau))r(\tau)d\tau
$$

Comment: Thank you very much!